# How to change grouping mode on explorer by autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make files in explorer grouped by type shortcut. I'm folowing this post: [Automate windows folders (sort by date, name, etc)](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=64414)

The `MsgBox, % oWin.Document.GroupBy` line shows current group settings, but `oWin.Document.GroupBy := "prop:System.ItemTypeText;"` show an erorr "Element not found"

Here the whole script:

```
IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
q:: ;explorer - sort files by date modified
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ExploreWClass
q:: ;explorer - sort files by date modified
WinGet, hWnd, ID, A
for oWin in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
{
    if (oWin.HWND = hWnd)
    {    
        MsgBox, % oWin.Document.GroupBy         
        oWin.Document.GroupBy := "prop:System.ItemTypeText;" ;does not work 
        oWin.Document.CurrentViewMode := 4
        oWin.Document.SortColumns := "prop:-System.DateModified;" ;sort by date modified descending (newest first)    
        break
    }
}
oWin := ""
return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Use of try/catch in dealing with COM errors](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Try.htm#ex_el)**:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass

    q:: ;explorer - sort files by date modified
    
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ExploreWClass

    q:: ;explorer - sort files by date modified
        WinGet, hWnd, ID, A
        for oWin in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
        {
            if (oWin.HWND = hWnd)
            {
                ; MsgBox, % oWin.Document.GroupBy ;show current sort columns
                Try oWin.Document.GroupBy := "prop:System.ItemTypeText;"  
                oWin.Document.CurrentViewMode := 4
                oWin.Document.SortColumns := "prop:-System.DateModified;" ;sort by date modified descending (newest first)    
                    break
            }
        }
        oWin := ""
    return
    
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Does not work: the error is gone, but the grouping is not applied.

Comment: That's a pity. Works here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have given up on that one and just used alt hotkey: `Send !VG`.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.